# Login for Shared Mailbox

Tags: office-365, exchange-server

We have a website with a contact form.  The form makes an API call.  The API server then logs in via IMAP to send an email.  This worked great when we maintained our own mail server.  However, we have recently switched to Office 365.

I have created a shared mailbox (info@domain.com).  According to the sources I've found, to access this shared mailbox you would typically login using any licensed user credentials that have access.  This is a problem.  I don't want to put my credentials (or anyone else's) in the API server code (or config file).

Is there any way to set up a generic login for a shared mailbox?  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en

Comment: That doesn't help me in any way.  First, it's Google, not Office 365.  Second, delegation would still require authentication (It's basically what I'm doing now with an Exchange "Shared" inbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the Office 365 Admin Center, Active Users (https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/users) and you'll notice there is an unlicensed "user" for the shared inbox. If you click on this user, you can then reset the password and provide any password you want.